# Java Standalone Application is behaving as inconsistency with long runs in windows-10

Tags: java, windows-10

Can you please any one help on this problem?
we have a Java Desktop application(JDK8/JRE8-32bit) which will run on Windows-10

we are capturing times for each Runs for huge data.
Run1: 76min:24sec
Run2: 80min:34sec
Run3: 57min:8sec
Run4: 76min:50sec
we are not able to predict for next Run how much time we can get.

### Windows 10-configuration

Socket-1
No.of Cores=8
No.of Logical Processors=8
Base Speed : 1.99 GHz
RAM: 16GB
Note: If we run the same application in 8GB Of windows-10 then it is taking very huge time nearly 3 hrs for each Run.

In code we have captured the timings for each line execution at attribute level, but it was showing the time difference in mills sec's and this difference was some time increasing/decreasing during executing of application.

### CODE:

```
        Block nextSubBlock = this.getNextSubBlock();
        while (nextSubBlock != null && !this.endOfFile()) {
            while (!this.blockReached(nextSubBlock) && !this.endOfFile()) {
                this.processAttribute(this.next());
            }
            nextSubBlock.processBlock();
            nextSubBlock = this.getNextSubBlock();
        }
        while (!this.endOfBlock() && !this.endOfFile()) {
            this.processAttribute(this.next());
        }

        this.setStaticCounters();
        this.processRepeatedBlocks()
```

Comment: Does the machine do anything else?

Comment: In this machine only java application is running and closed remaining all, but don't know if any other processes are running background which is related to windows.

Comment: Sounds like memory pressure matters to your setup.  I would suggest you learn to use a profiler.  A good place to start is attaching visualvm to get better insights in what is going on.

Comment: Captured the heap dump for each run before starting of next run with the Profiler but did not see much difference in Leak suspects Reports. can you please tell us is there any other way to see the unique JVM performance.

Comment: Every time taking the fresh results by completely erasing the Data base.

Comment: What did visualvm tell you?

Comment: Also the database performance might be relevant depending on the workload.

Comment: captured some of the CPU profile snapshot view using visualVM for this import process, but it's not showing the complete time, should see only particular span of that live data. Is there any way to see complete time statistics along with java memory for each RUN.

Comment: observed one more point in heap dump files after import process for 3 RUNS, it's showing  same leak suspect report and same number of total occupied Java memory(104.1MB) for all these even though time difference is there for each run, how it is possible?

Comment: Details: Suspect:1- The class "au.com.invensys.scada.syscfg.iscadaobjects.IScadaEntity", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc01a0b80", occupies 67,704,968 (62.03%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.Hashtable$Entry[]" loaded by "<system class loader>". Suspect:2 -The class "au.com.invensys.scada.syscfg.cfgimport.Block", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc01a0b80", occupies 19,445,744 (17.82%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in class "au.com.invensys.scada.syscfg.cfgimport.Block", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc01a0b80".

Comment: If you have a memory leak, fix that first.  Then look at the cpu profiler.